# Adding virtual interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces is not permanent

Tags: networking, interface

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 in a VM from a Windows host.
I have added virtual interfaces to /etc/network/interfaces, like in

```
auto eth0:18
iface eth0:18 inet static
address 192.168.46.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.46.255
network 192.168.46.0
```

I bring them up with

```
sudo ifdown --all
sudo ifup --all
```

This works fine, but once i restart the VM, the changes are gone again.
I have the impression that even if i leave the VM open, but the host goes to hibernate and suspend, then the interface config on the VM is gone again?!

What do i need to do to make these changes static, so that they are active once the VM has booted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a graphical user interface installed, Network Manager overwrites the changes on reboot. Remove it using

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager
```

re-edit the interfaces file and reboot to see if the changes are persistent.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1767716