# dummy network interface on start-up

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I'm currently using Ubuntu Server 16.04 x86_64 on a Virtualbox VM.

I need to set up a dummy interface that comes up on boot. I have added the module dummy to /etc/modules and tried to bring it up puting the following lines in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto dummy0
iface dummy0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

But after reboot I can't see the interface, if I made it manualy using ip link command it cames up without a problem so I'd like to ask if any one knows of a method to make this interface como up at boot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the network manager taking over?

As per [this wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager), check that /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf contains:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Check that etc/network/interfaces wasn't overwritten, if so, add your changes again, then reboot. See what happens.

If you don't need the NetworkManager, you may remove it.

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager
```

Check this related [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549200/adding-virtual-interfaces-in-etc-network-interfaces-is-not-permanent).

Comment: I checked and I'm not using network manager, I'm trying to use pre-up and up commands but so far I still can't make the dummy interface come up at boot, will keep trying and report back if I suced. Tx for your suggestion.

Comment: Check this out: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=43090. You may need to edit edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. This may be relevant too: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110496/cloned-linux-system-and-etc-udev-rules-d-70-persistent-net-rules

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on two fronts, first I was trying to use the wrong type of network interface, what I needed was a tap interface not a dummy one. Second I use this post https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=830777&page=2 to make the tap permanent.

I modified it to use "ip" as the pre-up comand as follow:
ip tuntap add dev tap9 mode tap

And now when I restart my VPS the tap interface is there.

Tx all for your suggestions.